# OOP Pygame player_x variable changing but no changes happen in display

Tags: python, pygame

Hi am pretty new to programming in general so this might be a pretty dumb problem. Am currently trying to learn more about OOP by making a game.

while the value of player_x is changing for some reasons its not moving as I expected.

main.py

```
import pygame, settings, obstacles, npc, player
from utils import *
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((settings.WIDTH, settings.HEIGHT))
FPS = pygame.time.Clock()

player = player.Player(window)

Loop

run = True

while run:
    FPS.tick(settings.FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                settings.PLAYER_X -= 5
                print(settings.PLAYER_X)

    pygame.display.update()
```

player.py

```
import pygame, settings
pygame.init()

class Player():
    def __init__(self, window) -> None:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, settings.OLIVE, (settings.PLAYER_X, settings.PLAYER_Y, settings.PLAYER_WIDTH, settings.PLAYER_HEIGHT)) # (x, y, width, height)
    
    def player_control(self):
        pass
```

settings.py

```
WIDTH = 1440
HEIGHT = 720
FPS = 60

PLAYER_X = 100
PLAYER_Y = 200
PLAYER_WIDTH = 50 
PLAYER_HEIGHT = 50

OLIVE = (136, 196, 23)
```

Comment: You only draw the player when it is created. You  need to draw it every frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move your `player`, you need to:

- Render your `player` in every while-loop
- Render your `player` with the updated `PLAYER_X`

And to achieve it, you need a few modification in your code:

1. Create a function to render in your `player.py` and call it in the loop instead of render a `player` in `__init__`, which will only be called once.
2. Reference `settings.PLAYER_X` only once in the `__init__` in `player.py` and update the variable of the `player` object when key are pressed.
3. At the end of every loop, render the `player` object.

---

**player.py**

```
import pygame, settings
pygame.init()

class Player():
    def __init__(self, window) -> None:
        self.window = window
        self.color = settings.OLIVE
        self.X = settings.PLAYER_X
        self.Y = settings.PLAYER_Y
        self.W = settings.PLAYER_WIDTH
        self.H = settings.PLAYER_HEIGHT
        self.render()
    
    def render(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.window, self.color, (self.X, self.Y, self.W, self.H)) 
        
    def player_control(self):
        pass
```

---

**main.py**

```
import pygame, settings, player
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((settings.WIDTH, settings.HEIGHT))
FPS = pygame.time.Clock()

player = player.Player(window)

run = True

while run:
    FPS.tick(settings.FPS)
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                player.X -= 5
                print(player.X)
    window.fill((0, 0, 0))
    player.render()
    pygame.display.update()
```